# How to use libcinder with c#?

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, cinder

I recently came across [libcinder](https://libcinder.org/) which seems to be promising for **creative coding**.

It's for c++ but I'm more familiar with c#. Is there a way to use `libcinder` with c#?

Or maybe in c# world, there is some other collection of libraries / framework for the same purpose?

The first thing I'd like to try is to open an image then draw lines/rectangles on it, the second thing in my list is to open a live video and then draw some thing on the video. Is it the best choice to use cinder or should I just use OpenCV with c++/c#?

Answer (score 0):

What libcinder feature are you looking for in "C# World". Many of the features listed on that link are already available in C# (.NET) since 2005-2008.

Example things that C#/.NET can do (same as libcinder):

- Standalone Apps
- Internet I/O
- Platform Specific API's (PInvoke)
- Xml & JSON Parsers
- Full I/O Stuff
- UI Events
- Multi Touch
- Communication API's
- 3D & 2D Graphics
- Multimedia